# Restarting with stat when trying dash app

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am try to learn the dash app package in python and I started with the basic tutorial as follows,

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(' Dash Tutorials')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But I am getting the following error,

```
* Restarting with stat

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

When I put %tb, the following is what is showing up,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5d4a332652ef> in <module>()
     32 
     33 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 34     app.run_server(debug=True)

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.pyc in run_server(self, port, debug, **flask_run_options)
    564                    debug=False,
    565                    **flask_run_options):
--> 566         self.server.run(port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.pyc in run(self, host, port, debug, **options)
    839         options.setdefault('use_debugger', self.debug)
    840         try:
--> 841             run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
    842         finally:
    843             # reset the first request information if the development server

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.pyc in run_simple(hostname, port, application, use_reloader, use_debugger, use_evalex, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type, threaded, processes, request_handler, static_files, passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
    735         from werkzeug._reloader import run_with_reloader
    736         run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval,
--> 737                           reloader_type)
    738     else:
    739         inner()

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.pyc in run_with_reloader(main_func, extra_files, interval, reloader_type)
    263             reloader.run()
    264         else:
--> 265             sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
    266     except KeyboardInterrupt:
    267         pass

SystemExit: 1
```

I've tried several things to solve this problem. But I am not able to find a solution for it. Can anybody please help me in solving this issue?

Thanks

Comment: A couple questions that may or may not help debug this: 1. What's the `if` statement in the last call of your traceback? 2. Are you running on Windows?

Comment: Try debug=False if you're using Spyder.

Comment: @ScarletAndGray Thanks! It works for Jupyter notebook as well.

Answer (score 2):

Run it with the debug mode disabled:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```